# AWS Enabling CORS for my API triggering a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, http-status-code-500

I managed to create an AWS Lambda that does two things: writes on a dynamo DB and sends an SMS to a mobile number. Then I call this Lambda through a API Gateway POST call, and it works great from the Test section on AWS console but it gives error both on Postman and my own website. I inserted a callback to handle CORS on Lambda and deployed + enabled CORS on my API via console and deployed it but still get errors:

Errors via postman call: {
"message": "Internal server error"
}

Errors via my website (jquery ajax POST call): Lambda calling failed: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{"message": "Internal server error"}","responseJSON":{"message":"Internal server error"},"status":500,"statusText":"error"}

This is my lambda code

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
const SNS = new AWS.SNS();
const tableName = "#####";  
let params = {
                PhoneNumber: 'mynumber####',
                Message: 'Someone wrote!'
             };

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    dynamodb.putItem({
        "TableName": tableName,
        "Item" : {
            "Id": {
                N: event.Id
            },
            "Type": {
                S: event.Type
            }
        }
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error putting item into dynamodb failed: '+err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Success in writing, now starting to send SMS');
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                SNS.publish(params, function(err, data) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("Error in sending sms alarm");
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("SMS alarm sent!");
                        resolve(data);
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    });
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't think permissions on lambda are the problem here, since testing it on console works both on writing on dynamo both sending the sms to my cellphone.

If I click from here on API Endpoint I get the same error {"message": "Internal server error"}
[image]

Comment: Do any errors get printed? Check the cloudwatch logs. I doubt the `event` has `Id` and `Type` top level in it.

Comment: @luk2302 The weird thing is that clouwatch logs ONLY when the call is made from AWS Console lambda tests

Comment: Then your API gateway has no permission to invoke the lambda. Or points to the wrong lambda: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-lambda-stage-variable-500/

Comment: @luk2302 Dunno, yesterday my lambda had just the dynamo db functionality and I managed to call it correctly from Postman with no error, logging correctly on cloudwatch. Today I have added the SMS sending functionality and started to receive these errors.

Comment: [Simplify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-async-await.html) your async calls to AWS e.g. `await dynamodb.putItem(params).promise()` and `await SNS.publish(params).promise()`. Related: your current code is incorrectly making the Lambda handler callback before it completes the SNS publish. Don't use callback (at all). Just use the promise versions of everything, including the Lambda function handler.

Comment: @jarmod Sorry I don't understand. How would you write then the lambda?

Comment: Example of making async calls to AWS SDK [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-async-await.html). Example of proxy integration HTTP response [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html).

Comment: Oh ok, got It, thanks a lot! Now I'll try It in a couple of hours :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: instead of making an AWS HTTP API, make a AWS REST API, that is much more complex and offers more personalization for CORS, letting you set them and headers.